# How to program quick interaction in multiplayer browser games?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, game-engine

I have been programming a lot of multiplayer browser games in past which needed some interaction between player, but since it was more about strategies and "building" games, interaction was not the main problem.

I was able to do all of the stuff with just jquery, ajax and php like this:

1. someone makes a change to the overall content of the game - ajax fires an php script which stores this change in database.
2. your client side code continuously runs an ajax script, each time firing an php script which searches database for changes and if there are any, you are notified or content (html code) of your page is updated based on those changes.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
setInterval(function() {    
    $.ajax({
        url: "checkUpdates.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            // do the changes based on the returned data
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

But now I am developing games where interaction is the main factor. Let us say something like a tennis where you need to track the position of ball for both players as well as their movements.
Simple approach is to store those values in database and update page content with the mentioned function. But this is not possible now because if you fire the ajax function in very quick successions then it will slow down browser. Another issue is that there is a "big" delay between firing the ajax function and making changes based on the result.

Therefore my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to solve this problem with ajax? Some approach which would overcome the mentioned problem (firing ajax function every e.g. 0.1 second).
2. Is it even possible to make this work in php and relation databases or you need to use something like node.js/python for backend with nosql databases? (which would be faster I guess)
3. What is the current state of art in this field?

Even though this might be quite a broad question, I have not find anything which would strictly say that the mention approach is not suitable.

Comment: You're looking for web sockets.

Comment: websockets https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/demos/tag/tech:websockets

Comment: websockets or at the very least something like knockoutjs or angular where you can bind to the data for instant UI updates.

Comment: ^ not necessary for the game. Knockout and Angular isn't going to make updating the UI any faster, just helps organize/simplify the code. ('simplify' being an opinionated statement)

Comment: I was just about to say "What about websockets?" when I saw the 3-4 comments before me saying the exact same thing.